# git ftp + Bitbucket pipelines + SSH public key authentication failed: Unable to open public key file

Tags: git, bitbucket, sftp, bitbucket-pipelines

I am trying to configure Bitbucket pipeline to deploy branch on server through SFTP, but getting error on logs : SSH public key authentication failed: Unable to open public key file

This is my bitbucket-pipelines.yml file looks like:

```
image: php:7.1.1
pipelines:
  default:
    - step:
        script:
          - apt-get update
          - apt-get -qq install git-ftp
          - git ftp init -vv --user $FTP_USERNAME --passwd $FTP_PASSWORD sftp://host_ip_address/public_html/
```

Comment: is there a `-i` option to `git ftp` that can point to an `id_rsa` file that doesn't require a password?

Comment: didn't make any difference, same error

Comment: It was a question. `scp` for example has a `-i` option that allows you to point to your `.ssh` file. Since it seems like `git ftp` is made by some user, you can ask him/her if there's an option to point to your ssh key